# Testing service layer without DAO

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mocking

Can you give me an example of how I test my service layer without the DAO using mock objects, Spring or any other framework. My Java code looks like this:

```
public int myServiceMethod(int number) {

    int myInt = Factory.getDAOImpl.getNumber();
    return myInt + number * 8;
}
```

I want to test the logic of myServiceMethod but without testing the DAO method.
Is it possible? Do I have to refactor it? Can you show me an example of how to test this simple method.
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, you would just need to mock your DAO (for example using [Mockito](http://mockito.org/)), and fix a number to be returned.

```
DAOImpl myDao = mock(DAOImpl.class);
when(myDao.getNumber()).thenReturn(7);
```

When calling the method `getNumber`, you'll always get 7. Pass this DAO when creating your service, and write your test as normal:

```
assertEquals(224, service.myServiceMethod(4));
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Since DAOImpl is a package-private class and it can be instanciated only through the factory, the compiler will complain.